# Remove rows from a Gtk.Treeview with Mono

Tags: mono, gtk#

I have a treeview control( multiple selection supported) with a liststore attached. I need to remove some of the rows at some point. I can do that be clearing the liststore( ListStore.Clear()) and then repopulating it with items but when I set the liststore as model of the treeview I get a crash. Anybody has a better solution for removing rows/items from a treeview ?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't crash. Are you clearing and populating it from the GUI thread, or some worker thread? GTK+ isn't thread-safe, so if you're using threads make sure you use Gtk.Application.Invoke or [similar](http://www.mono-project.com/Responsive_Applications).

Note that there's also

```
Gtk.ListStore.Remove (ref TreeIter iter)
```

Comment: sorry to dig up an old question, but could you help me in linking the treeIter to the selected row, I am a bit confused about how to do this.

Comment: Please create a new question.